# Calling ajax request continually until a certain search request is found

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to keep sending AJAX GET requests to a certain page that inputs from a cgi script until a specific set of keystrokes shows up.

However, my requests aren't coming up continuously, in fact they aren't even taking place when I am using a function and trying to call the function. I had to use the complete with the success, because for whatever reason, with the success I could not properly store the value retrieved.

Here is what I have:

```
function posts() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://checkvaluestatus.sh',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data_response.responseText);
        },
        complete: function(data_response) {
            alert(data_response.responseText);
            var viewport = data_response.responseText;
            var version = viewport.match(/Release:[^=]*/);

            if (version != null) {
                console.log(version);

            } else {
                posts();
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('failed');
            posts(); //calling the ajax again.
        }
    });
```

Is there not a way to keep sending requests based on a condition being met and having the value still stored?

This is my AJAX call that worked to print the value:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://checkvaluestatus.sh',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data_response.responseText);
    },
    complete: function(data_response) {
        alert(data_response.responseText);
        var viewport = data_response.responseText;
        var version = viewport.match(/Release:[^=]*/);
        document.write(version);
    },
});
```

Comment: in your `success` method, you are giving a parameter of `data` to the callback even though you're trying to access `data_response` on the next line. With the code given, `data_response` would be `undefined` there. Was this a typo?

Comment: That worked when I called the ajax request on its own once. It also worked when I changed it. However, the initial ajax call is still not being made.

Comment: @JDoe can you add the code where you are calling the `posts()` function? And you say that "with the success I could not properly store the value retrieved", can you show the code where you are trying to store the value

Comment: I just call posts() outside of the function and I thought it would repeat if the condition wasn't met. I'm editing my post to include the ajax call that actually worked for me on it's own. However, the variable version is not available outside of the call, so I do not know how to validate it outside of the function. Since there is no longer async: false available on jQuery.

Comment: Otherwise I would do if(version != null){document.write (version)}; else{post()};

Answer (score 0):

salam,
the value you are looking for in success function is the 'data' ,not "data_response.responseText" because in "success" function data is your response text ,but in the "complete" function "data_response" is a jqXHR object contain more information.

to print your text in success function replace

```
alert(data_response.responseText);
```

by

```
alert(data);
```

for more details "[jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)"